99 camaro overheating
We have put a lot of money in this car but still can’t figure it out .
Got a new radiator new thermostat new hoses but I’m thinking the fans aren’t working it gets over 210 and still no fan . Can all these fan fuses be popped out and replaced ?

I suggest that before you replace any more parts, you use a scan tool to read your coolant temperature and see if it agrees with the temperature gauge.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a Z28 or V6?

Original fan(s) may be worn out.

210° as shown on the gauge in the dash is about the normal operating temperature for the 1999 Camaro, whether V6 or Z28. If it's anywhere in that ballpark, you wouldn't necessarily be considered as "overheating". You don't even get to the "danger zone" (no Kenny Loggins pun intended) until you reach upwards of 245-ish.
If you still believe you are overheating, you can test your fans and relays. You may want to do the following:
You should have two fans in the front of your Camaro regardless if it's a V6 or Z28 (V8). These are tripped on via the ECU. One side will come on for the engine while the other side will come on if the AC is turned on. I believe they also will have fast and slow speeds associated with them (I don't know how that works, though).
First thing to do is to check to see if the AC turns on a fan. If not, then you need to pull the wiring and apply 12v power directly to the fan plug. If the fans turn on in either instance, you can eliminate them from your search. Note: It is HIGHLY doubtful both fans would die at the same time, but it is possible.
The next thing you should try is to see if the relays are viable. These you'll find in the engine compartment in the fuse box. If you pull the cover, there'll be a diagram which should point out which relays are for the fans. You need to test them. You can do this with a known good relay (new is the optimal choice). You can (if you have enough hands), energize the relays (pulled out of the socket) and then checking continuity across the pins. You can easily Google for a diagram of how a relay works and which pins do what.
While you're in here testing relays, you can also test to ensure the wiring is good from the fuse box to the fans by jumping from the power to what goes out to the fans. Test both. You never know. Your car may have had some rodent help to disconnect the fans.

I am not familiar with Camaro, but: the thermostat in this car opens at 180F / 82C (somewhat low or retro in my EU understanding for 1999 car, but anyway), 20F or 10C higher the thermostat has to be wide open and fans at quiet speed and 10F/5C more one would expect fans to run at full speed. While the engine itself may be OK at 210F/100C or even higher and this may be even normal in a hot weather, no fan blowing at this temperature (at least at low speed) is still questionable.

@fraxinus - The OE opening temp is 195° F on the thermostat for V6 (3.8L) and 187° F on the V8 (5.7L LS1).

Based on these temperatures, 210F looks more or less normal.
